# Demo and game sharing same rules?

Tags: ps4, psn

As the most ps4 users know it is possible and allowed to share ps4 games with another account if the primary and secondary console settings are set correctly but what about demos?

If I download a demo on a german account for example, I still can play it on the US account too, I've tested that already. But is a demo still playable if I would delete the german account? A full game would then be locked and unplayable.

Answer (score 1):

Demos are subject to the same restrictions as full games. If you license a German demo to your system and then delete the German account the rights to the download are removed. The US account can only access it as long as the licensing account is still present on the system.